# What language rules governs that `T&&` in a templated array-by-&& function argument is *not* a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, forwarding-reference

A static analysis tool I'm using prompts me that I need to `std::forward` the argument of the following function down the call chain:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
constexpr void f(T (&& arr)[size]) { /* linter: use std::forward on 'arr' here */ }
```

as it identifies the function parameter type as a forwarding reference.

A simple test on several compilers show, however, that this is **not** a forwarding reference. The following example

```
void g() {
    int a[3]{1, 2, 3};
    f(a);  // #1
}
```

is rejected at `#1` ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/11hq1bjKj)), explicitly pointing our that the function parameter is an rvalue reference:

> ```
>  error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int (&&)[3]' to lvalue of type 'int [3]'
> ```

#### Question

- What language rules governs that `T&&` in a templated array-by-`&&` function argument as in `f` above is not a forwarding reference?

Comment: For the warning about `std::forward`, do you use `std::move`/nothing?

Comment: @Jarod42 The warning is emitted no matter if I use `std::move` or nothing (the associated rule is "use `std::forward` for forwarding references"). For now I've changed the signature to `void f(T const (&& arr)[size])` (which still works for the specific purpose of mine) after which the tool accepts it as an rvalue reference and not a forwarding one. As soon as the tool vendor accepts my "false positive bug report" I'll use an appropriately tagged inline suppression instead of the `const` hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant section is [[temp.deduct.call]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.call#1.sentence-2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
> template parameter type (call it `P`) that contains
> template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction
> with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`)
> as described below. **If removing references and cv-qualifiers from
> `P` gives**   `std::initializer_list<P′>` or **`P′[N]` for some `P′`
> and `N` and the argument is a non-empty initializer list**
> ([dcl.init.list]), **then deduction is performed instead for each
> element of the initializer list independently**, taking `P′` as
> separate function template parameter types `P′i` and the `i`:th
> initializer element as the corresponding argument. [...]

Meaning [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.call#3.sentence-3) does not apply for a `P` that was originally an array reference type (once it reaches /3, /3 applies per element).

However, if we return to the section above we may note that it comes with the restriction

> [...]  and the argument is a non-empty initializer list [...]

meaning a call, for OP's example function `f`, like

```
f({1, 2, 3});  // [temp.deduct.call]/1 applies
```

But what about the case where the argument is not an initializer list, but an array?

```
int arr[3]{1, 2, 3};
f(arr);
```

[[temp.deduct.call]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.call#2) have special rules for arrays, but it does not apply as `P` is a reference type, meaning we *do* end up at [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.call#3):

> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of P's type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.
>
> **A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter** that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])). If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

The function parameter in `f`, however, is an rvalue reference to `T[size]`, which is not a template parameter. This governs the case for when the argument is not an initializer list (and arguably also that case).

Comment: Why [temp.deduct.call]/1 is needed here? In `T (&& arr)[size]`, the rvalue reference is to `T[size]`, which does not satisfy «A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter», because `T[size]` is not a template parameter.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I was in the progress of writing the expanded answer for the case where the argument is not a (non-empty) initializer list (answer updated now). Doesn't [temp.deduct.call]/1 arguably cover the case of an initializer list argument prior to landing at [temp.deduct.call]/3? Whereas we land at the latter for when the argument is an array.